# menu contitional based on category

Tags: wordpress, menu, conditional-statements, categories

I am trying to change the menu items in a menu by making a condition when a particular category is active the menu items will change.  This is as close as I can get, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php if( is_category(array('commercial','commercial-filtration','commercial-water-softeners','reverse-osmosis'),'category') ) { ?>
      menu='commercial'
<?php  } else { ?>
      menu='primary'
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: If the function is used outside the loop, I'm assuming this in your header.php file, then use this function passing it the post ID get_the_category($post_id) to get the categories of the current post.  Then you can loop over the categories returned and check for those names you have specified.

Comment: I am trying to use it in my functions.php file

Comment: Show the whole code then so I can help you, it makes it very difficult if I can't see the entire picture.

Comment: @cboy this one possible with pass your menu argument. Review my code i have tested in my wp

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for your condition based menu. (Create theme location using [register_nav_menus()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus))

```
<?php  
$menu_name = ( is_category(array('commercial','commercial-filtration','commercial-water-softeners','reverse-osmosis' ))) ? 'primary' : 'footermenu'; ?> 

    <?php if (has_nav_menu($menu_name)) : ?>
        <nav>
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu(array(
                'theme_location' => $menu_name,
                'container' => '',
                'container_class' => '',
                'container_id' => '',
                'menu_class' => 'enumenu_ul menu',
                'depth' => 2,
            ));
            ?>
        </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a conditional menu plugin.  I am not understanding why people click on my rating to give me a lower rating when I ask a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

make two different menu....
might be it helps and change condition as per your requirement

```
<?php if ( is_page('projects') ) : ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu' => 'conditional-menu-name', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu' => 'Primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```